# Make image move using keypress - jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, keydown

I'm trying to make an image move using keypress. I have figured out where the problem is, I just haven't been able to fix it. The problem has to do with what's focused when the page loads. I fixed it using `tabindex`. In my opinion was that a poor solution.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hero").focus();
    ("#hero").on('keydown', function(event){
        switch(event.which){
            case 37:
                $('#hero').stop().animate({
                    left: '-=10'
                }); //left arrow key
                break;
            case 38: 
                $('#hero').stop().animate({
                            top: '-=10'
                }); //up arrow key
                break;
            case 39:
                $('#hero').stop().animate({
                    left: '+=10'
                }); //right arrow key
                break;
            case 40: 
                $('#hero').stop().animate({
                    top: '+=10'
                }); //bottom arrow key
                break;
        }
    });

});
```

One would think `.focus()` is the way to go but for some reason that doesn't work.

[**Here is the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/PuPZF/)

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing $ in the third line of your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give hero a tabindex like this

```
$("#hero").attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PuPZF/4/)

Comment: You code didn't do exactly what I wanted but it helped me solve it anyway - thanks!

Comment: @Nilzone- check my update, gave it a tabindex so you can focus it

Comment: @Nilzone- You can even make hero a class and choose to move which car like this http://jsfiddle.net/PuPZF/6/

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** use `focus` on an image, what you can do is **create** a hidden **input** field and focus and read key strokes inside that input box.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/PuPZF/2/ *(Based on Anton's code)*

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you are looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/bDMnX/7/)

HTML:

```
<div id="pane">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#pane {
    position:relative;
    width:300px; height:300px;
    border:2px solid red;
}

#box {
    position:absolute; top:140px; left:140px;
    width:20px; height:20px;          
    background-color:black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var pane = $('#pane'),
    box = $('#box'),
    w = pane.width() - box.width(),
    d = {},
    x = 3;

function newv(v,a,b) {
    var n = parseInt(v, 10) - (d[a] ? x : 0) + (d[b] ? x : 0);
    return n < 0 ? 0 : n > w ? w : n;
}

$(window).keydown(function(e) { d[e.which] = true; });
$(window).keyup(function(e) { d[e.which] = false; });

setInterval(function() {
    box.css({
        left: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 37, 39); },
        top: function(i,v) { return newv(v, 38, 40); }
    });
}, 20);
```

Comment: I have seen that answer in another post thank you. Is it the answer that I'm looking for? Both yes and no. It's a neat solution, but I kinda wanna know why my code doesn't work